# jQuery Cookie not being read

Tags: jquery, cookies, stylesheet

I was wondering if you were able to help me at all. I am trying to read a cookie in jQuery with regards to a style switcher but it just isn't playing fair at all. I have had a look around on Google and also on the jquery cookie plugin website to no avail

I am using the jquery.cookie plugin.

I can set the cookie just fine, but reading it is another matter altogether.

I am setting the cookie to be the last stylesheet used and when I reload the page I am wanting that value to be used as the stylesheet that is loaded.

I am using the function as follows to read the cookie:

```
$(document).ready((function() {
            if($.cookie("css")) {
                $('style[id="colours"]').text('@import url("css/' + $.cookie("css") + '.css');
            });
        });
```

However, when I use this the rest of the jQuery breaks. I have tried it using just $function() and I have put an if else in there and it just isn't working.

If I take it out, the page and jquery loads just fine.

As I say, the cookie sets fine. I have tested it with an alert and also in firebug and on change the cookie changes.

This is what I have used to set the cookie:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#green').click(function() {
                $('style[id="colours"]').text('@import url("css/green.css");')
                $.cookie("css",$(this).attr('id'), {expires: 30, path: '/'});
            });
        });
```

You can view what I have so far here: http://www.chriswilcox.me.uk/test/cv and see what I mean. I have commented out the reading of the cookie as it breaks everything else.

I would totally appreciate any help you guys and gals have to offer.

Comment: you should always use console to debug your code. You'll see some errors.

Comment: Hi roasted, I have been using that and the only error I get is that I am missing a ) after the arguments. It isn't the case though as I have if ($.cookie("css")) <- this is the ) it wants at the end. I do that and then it tells me I am missing it from "css")). I just can't figure it out at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has an extra `)`

```
$(document).ready(function () { // also here you had an extra (
    if ($.cookie("css")) {
        $('style[id="colours"]').text('@import url("css/' + $.cookie("css") + '.css);');
         // you are missing another one up there at @import
    } // here you don't need to close )
});
```

Comment: Hi Spokey, I removed that and it still isn't reading the cookie. It still messes up the rest of the other jquery :(

Comment: Oh, I meant I had removed the extra )

Comment: if you do `$(function() {alert($.cookie("css")) });`, what value do you get?, also can you uncomment the function on your site so I can see the errors.

Comment: I get the value that is stored by the cookie. Storing works just fine. It's just reading it that it doesn't like one bit

Comment: Ya, but could you uncomment the function as @Spokey told you

Comment: @Spokey. I've uncommented the function

Comment: @Chris check my edit above, you still have an extra `(` and you're missing a `)` at `@import`

Comment: @Spokey. Thank you so much. That extra ( and missing ) fixed it all. I was staring at it for half an hour and I wasn't getting any feedback from firebug either. Thank you thank you thank you